# Is there a way to change min value for Remesh modifier > Voxel > Voxel size property?

Tags: modifiers

I have to remesh with a voxel size less than 0.1 mm, but there is a hard limit set to 0.1 mm (0.0001 m).

bpy.context.object.modifiers["Remesh"].bl_rna.properties["voxel_size"].hard_min

I know one possible workaround is to use object scale, but that is quite cumbersome since I would have to change property values of all other (existing) modifiers as well.

Comment: can you apply the modifier, or does it need to be dynamic?

Comment: The limit is there for a reason. At lower values you're likely to encounter an arithmetic error in OpenVDB (see [T77878](https://developer.blender.org/T77878)). You can change the limit if you compile Blender yourself, but that is arguably more cumbersome than working with the object scale.

Comment: Frederik: Yes, it should be dynamic.

Comment: Robert: OK, that explains it. I thought this limit was there only to avoid potential crashes when changing the scale. Compiling the Blender also crossed my mind - but really only for the moment :) It would definitely be more cumbersome than using mentioned workaround. Thanks.